# How can I select the distinct value of two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I'm not sure it's possible but I would like to select the distinct value of two tables columns.

Consider table1 like:

```
╔══════╗
║ col1 ║
╠══════╣
║ AAA  ║
║ AAA  ║
║ BBB  ║
║ BBB  ║
╚══════╝
```

and table2 like:

```
╔══════╗
║ col1 ║
╠══════╣
║ AAA  ║
║ BBB  ║
║ CCC  ║
║ CCC  ║
╚══════╝
```

The output I would like would be:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Obviously something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.col1 , table2.col1 FROM table1 , table2;
```

won't work.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ea77f/4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `UNION` would do the tricks

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT col1 FROM table2;
```

There is no need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword as `UNION` already handle duplicates.

FYI if you use `UNION ALL` the duplicates won't be handled anymore, then you would need to use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: thank you, good explanation. Never actually worked with `UNION` before that's why I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Just `union` will do the job, as it will filter out the duplicate records.

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 UNION SELECT col1 FROM table2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually go for sub-queries, but I think this is one of those times:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM (SELECT col1 FROM table1 UNION SELECT col1 FROM table2)
```